# Date Ranged IF statement in PowerQuery

Tags: date-range, powerquery, nested-if, m

I want to compare workforce details between Academic Years. I have a `Start Date` and an `End Date`.

I want to create custom columns which indicate if they were working in 2014/15, 2015/16 etc, then unpivot so I have a row for each year of employment.

so for 2015/16

```
*=if (([startdate] > 01/09/2015) and if([enddate] > 31/08/2016),"Yes","No")*
```

struggling a bit with M language, can you help with the syntax?

Comment: We have some simple guides on the [if expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299038.aspx#If) and just recently added documentation for how to use [#date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt742857.aspx). Try clicking around these guides and we have some examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
= if [startdate] > #date(2015,9,1) and [enddate] > #date(2016,8,31) then "Yes" else "No"
```

Note PQL / M is case sensitive.

Don't beat yourself up: after 3 years, the doco on both the if statement and date constants still doesn't exist AFAIK.

Comment: if you're interested in seeing better documentation, I created a UserVoice request: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/16204225-move-the-formula-language-m-documentation-to-d What do you think?

Comment: Docs certainly looks/works better than MSDN - you get my vote. But I noticed that's another variation on the name for this thing ... the Docs move is probably your last chance to sort out the name ... PQL?  https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11680242-provide-an-official-short-name-for-power-query-for